# Select from react-select not loading styles when dropdown is in another window

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I'm trying to open a new window programmatically in order to showcase information. In the new window we can filter out information based on the selection of the dropdows but the `select` from [react-select](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select) is not loading the styles in the new windows (dropdowns are fine anywhere else).

Here's the code I'm using:

```js
// app.tsx
import "./styles.css";

import React, { useState } from "react";

import Select from "react-select";

import WindowComponent from "./window";
import SelectComponent from "./form";

const options = [
  { value: "chocolate", label: "Chocolate" },
  { value: "strawberry", label: "Strawberry" },
  { value: "vanilla", label: "Vanilla" }
];

export default function App() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <a
        onClick={() => {
          setShow(!show);
        }}
      >
        Click me
      </a>
      {show && (
        <WindowComponent>
          <SelectComponent />
        </WindowComponent>
      )}
      <div style={{ marginTop: "50px" }}>Status: {show ? "True" : "False"}</div>
      <div style={{ marginTop: "50px" }}>
        <Select options={options} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Then we have `form.tsx`:

```js
// form.tsx
import React from "react";
import Select from "react-select";

const options = [
  { value: "chocolate", label: "Chocolate" },
  { value: "strawberry", label: "Strawberry" },
  { value: "vanilla", label: "Vanilla" }
];

const SelectComponent = () => {
  return <Select options={options} />;
};

export default SelectComponent;
```

And last but not least, how we generate the new windows:

```js
// windows.tsx
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const WindowComponent = ({ children }) => {
  /** ref to the new window opened */
  const windowRef = useRef<Window>(null);
  const [containerElement, setContainerElement] = useState<HTMLDivElement>(
    null
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    const newWindow = window.open("", "", "width=1200,height=400");
    windowRef.current = newWindow;

    const el = newWindow.document.createElement("div");
    setContainerElement(el);

    newWindow.document.body.appendChild(el);
    newWindow.document.title = `Graph`;

    return () => {
      newWindow.close();
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {containerElement && ReactDOM.createPortal(children, containerElement)}
    </div>
  );
};

export default WindowComponent;
```

I created a [codesandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-bird-pps4h8?file=/src/window.tsx).

If you open the sandbox environment, you can see that the dropdown renders correctly in the App component but when we click on "Click me" (don't forget to click on allow pop-up in your browser!) to open the new windows, the dropdown inside that windows is unstyled.

Any clue on what's going on and how to solve it? I'd appreciate it. <3

Answer (score 0):

Maybe theres a more elegant way of doing this but you can pull the style attributes using `Window.getComputedStyle()` ([link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)) and inject them into your new div element that you create within your useEffect hook.

Ive updated the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-water-v5ge37?file=/src/window.tsx:838-881). but basically I query 'App'
I just pulled one of the styles.

```
 let app = document.querySelector(".App");
 let compStyles = window.getComputedStyle(app);
```

and within your `el` that you created:

```
const el = newWindow.document.createElement("div");
```

I add the styles retrieved from .App:

```
el.style.textAlign = compStyles.textAlign;
```

Comment: Hi @aereli. Thanks for providing a solution! While I like the creativity of your solution, I think it's a little incomplete. :( In the real code, there wouldn't be a dropdown in App, so I can't copy the styles from there. :( I think the dropdown is not even rendered correctly, as the CSS likely comes from JavaScript code. I can't see any CSS file.